# MySQL replication: "Houston, We've Got a Problem"

Tags: mysql, replication

I ran into a problem with our replication server. Essentially, we have 2 databases (database1 and database2). Master server has both. Slave has only database1. There is a

```
Replicate_Do_DB: database1
```

set in CHANGE MASTER TO configuration.

Now what happened is - we are using code igniter, and one of the programers created database2 and started inserting info into it. Code igniter sets a default database to database1. Now the result is for every query he produced - I get an error on SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G:

```
Error 'Table 'database2.tbl40' doesn't exist' on query. Default database: 'database1'. Query: 'INSERT INTO `database2`.`tbl40` (`date`, `day`) VALUES ('2011-04-26', '2011-04-26')'
```

So essentially, I he fixed the problem afterwards, but the replication doesn't work as there is around 1000 queries that will produce that error for replication server.

My question is - is there some way to clear queries like that from the binlog?
Or I need to write a script that will do a

```
SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1;
```

for every query that produces and error ?

Comment: what are you doing..are you directly inserting records to slave in database2.?

Comment: yes, inserting stuff to database2, but, as far as I understand, code igniter mysql connection, selects database1 to begin with. It is all fine while it is happening on the master server, as it has both database1 and database2. But Slave server has only database1. So slave takes those queries from binlog, because database1 is selected, and tries to execute them on the slave, but on the slave server the database2 does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really don't care about that table, you can use [pt-slave-restart](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-slave-restart.html) on the slave and have it skip those problems.  I would be conservative about running it and make sure that you are only skipping queries for the table/database that you don't care about or at least for only a specific error.

You didn't post what the error code was in the output from SHOW SLAVE STATUS, but I suspect it is error 1146.

For example, this will skip all errors for 1146:

```
pt-slave-restart -u root -p pass --error-numbers 1146
```

Or, you could try skipping all errors that reference that table

```
pt-slave-restart -u root -p pass --error-text 'database2'
```

Another way to do this would be to set `replicate-ignore-db=database2` and restart MySQL on the slave, but there are some caveats to how that works that you should read about in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html)

Comment: Hi. Yes the error code is 1146. I dont think that the replicate-ignore-db=database2 will work, as code igniter selects the database1 to start with. But now when I look at it, you give me an idea: there is also a replicate_ignore_table, I could set that to `database2`.`tbl40`. and the replicate_wild_ignore_table is something that could be usefull.

Comment: Its me again, I think I solved it, I added a replicate-ignore-table=database2.tbl%, so it seems to be working so far ... Cheers for the idea :D

Comment: Looks like Houston can stop worrying now. +1 !!!

Answer (score 4):

I think the bigger problem here is your default database context was database1.  Thats's why  your slave tried to execute the update on database2 since it was specified in database2.table format.

Basically it's not safe to user db.table syntax with wildcards or you find yourself in the situation you did.  If you're wanting to use the wildcard do or ignores it's generally safer to always specify your default db using "use" and execute the query in that context.

Comment: totally agree. After this incident, I ll try making all the programers to show me, and test all their "awesome" queries before putting the production. Cheer for info! much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of being so draconian w/ the devs, give them guidance an pointers as needed.  Hopefully they're smart or they wouldn't have been hired as devs to begin with.  To audit the finer points of their queries you might just turn on general query logging in your qa/dev environment.  Look through that for new and potentially suspect queries.  Raise true issues you might find from that rather than making them hate you for wanting to review ever select column from table where primary_key=N; query

Comment: Cheers for a reply, I'll check out the query logging.